# How to check if time is greater than the total time between 2 dates in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I want to check whether the time 12.55(This is the format there, I have no access to edit the format) is greater than the total time between say 2 dates like  2015-10-12 10:00" and 2015-10-12 12:00.I've done the first part of finding diff but have no idea about doing the second which is finding the time is greater than time difference. Hope someone can help me!

```
var getDayTimeDiff = function(start, end){

    var date1 = new Date(start);
    var date2 = new Date(end);

    var diff = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();

    var msec = diff;
    var hh = Math.floor(msec / 1000 / 60 / 60);
    msec -= hh * 1000 * 60 * 60;
    var mm = Math.floor(msec / 1000 / 60);
    msec -= mm * 1000 * 60;
    var ss = Math.floor(msec / 1000);
    msec -= ss * 1000;

    return diff;
}



var timeDiff = getDayTimeDiff("2015-10-12 10:00","2015-10-12 12:00");
console.log(timeDiff); // 7200000


var time2Calc = "12.55";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just convert the time to millis and then compare the diff in millis like

```js
var getDayTimeDiff = function(start, end) {
  var date1 = new Date(start);
  var date2 = new Date(end);
  return date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
}

var toMillis = function(time) {
  var parts = time.split('.');
  return (parts[0] * 60 + +parts[1]) * 60 * 1000;
}



function test(t1, t2) {
  var timeDiff = getDayTimeDiff(t1, t2);


  var time2Calc = "12.55";
  var base = toMillis(time2Calc);

  var result = (Math.abs(timeDiff) > base);
  snippet.log(t1 + ' : ' + t2 + ' -> ' + result);
}

test("2015-10-12 10:00", "2015-10-12 23:00");
test("2015-10-12 10:00", "2015-10-12 12:00");
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: @user3407278 not really.... diff between `2015-10-12 10:00` and `2015-10-12 12:00` is 2 hours and between `2015-10-12 10:00` and `2015-10-12 10:00` is 0 hrs

Answer (score 0):

If by 'time 12.55' you mean 12 hours and 55 minutes, just convert this to milliseconds and compare to timeDiff.

**E:**

```
    function toMilli(time) {
        var a = time.split(".");
        return (a[0]*60 + a[1])*60*1000;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, its easy to work on date and time manipulations with Moment.js
like

```
var duration = moment.duration(end.diff(startTime));
var hours = duration.asMilliseconds();
```